# @ConfigurationProperties is not working with .YAML files

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am newbie to SpringBoot and trying to read the properties from YML file using in built SpringBoot annotations.

following is the code:

> AppProperties.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "patterns")
public class AppProperties {

    private List<PasswordPattern> password_patterns = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class PasswordPattern {
        private String pattern1;

        @Autowired
        public String getPattern1() {
            return pattern1;
        }

        public void setPattern1(String pattern1) {
            this.pattern1 = pattern1;
        }
    }

}
```

Test class where AppProperties being called

> Test1.java

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        AppProperties.PasswordPattern a = new AppProperties.PasswordPattern();

        System.out.println(a.getPattern1());
    }

}
```

> application.yml file

```
--- 
patterns: 
  password_patterns: 
  pattern1: "test"
```

EXPECTATION:  is that getPattern1() method should return the value read from the yml file

i referred many posts for such issues , but not getting what is the mistake i am doing. have i missed any specific annotation ? i red about

> @Autowired

it is related to dependency injection and i have used that also ...
please suggest

FURTHER EDITS:

after following the post from "Alexander pinkin" , getting following error :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'patterns.password-patterns' to java.util.Map<ja
va.lang.String, java.lang.String>:

    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String
] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

FURTHER EDIT 2:

> AppProperties.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "patterns")
public class AppProperties {

    private List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class Menu {
        private String pattern1;

        public String getPattern1() {
            return pattern1;
        }

        public void setPattern1(String pattern1) {
            this.pattern1 = pattern1;
        }

    }
}
```

> PasswordpatApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class PasswordpatApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PasswordpatApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PasswordpatApplication.class, args);

        AppProperties.Menu a = new AppProperties.Menu();
        LOG.info("hi");
        LOG.info(a.getPattern1());

    }
```

> application.yml

```
patterns: 
  password-patterns: 
  pattern1: test
```

OUTPUT:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-08-24 18:56:21.116  INFO 11712 --- [           main] c.e.passwordpat.Passwo
rdpatApplication   : Starting PasswordpatApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on PUNITP13
0066L with PID 11712 (C:\Users\irfan.sayed\Downloads\passwordpat\target\password
pat-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by irfan.sayed in C:\Users\irfan.sayed\Downloads\
passwordpat\target)
2018-08-24 18:56:21.131  INFO 11712 --- [           main] c.e.passwordpat.Passwo
rdpatApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: de
fault
2018-08-24 18:56:21.271  INFO 11712 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfig
ApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.Annotatio
nConfigApplicationContext@6c629d6e: startup date [Fri Aug 24 18:56:21 IST 2018];
 root of context hierarchy
2018-08-24 18:56:22.066  WARN 11712 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotatio
nBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static methods: pu
blic static void com.example.passwordpat.PasswordpatApplication.main(java.lang.S
tring[])
2018-08-24 18:56:23.887  INFO 11712 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMB
eanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-08-24 18:56:23.920  INFO 11712 --- [           main] c.e.passwordpat.Passwo
rdpatApplication   : Started PasswordpatApplication in 3.484 seconds (JVM runnin
g for 4.104)
2018-08-24 18:56:23.929  INFO 11712 --- [           main] c.e.passwordpat.Passwo
rdpatApplication   : hi
2018-08-24 18:56:23.931  INFO 11712 --- [           main] c.e.passwordpat.Passwo
rdpatApplication   : null
2018-08-24 18:56:23.938  INFO 11712 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfig
ApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationCo
nfigApplicationContext@6c629d6e: startup date [Fri Aug 24 18:56:21 IST 2018]; ro
ot of context hierarchy
2018-08-24 18:56:23.946  INFO 11712 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMB
eanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

now , nothing is getting printed on the console. neither any error OR exception

please suggest

Comment: You arent ever starting a spring context in your example, you would need to start one and obtain an instance of the configuration from the context.

Comment: thanks for comment. can you please elaborate ? any sample example ?

Comment: What happens if you change your `password_patterns` field name to `passwordPatterns`? (And if that doesn't work, change both to `passwordpatterns` exactly?)

Comment: try removing quotes from pattern1: "test" like this pattern1: test

Comment: Thanks Chrylis and Alien. I tried both of your options , but still null is coming

Comment: Looks like you have incorrect indentation in your yaml. `pattern1` should have one more intentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start Spring context and name your property "password-patterns" or "passwordPatterns".

This should work:

> AppProperties.java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "patterns")
public class AppProperties {

    private Map<String, String> passwordPatterns = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getPasswordPatterns() {
        return passwordPatterns;
    }
}
```

> DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private AppProperties appProperties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        LOG.info("pattern = {}", appProperties.getPasswordPatterns().get("pattern1"));
    }
}
```

> application.yml

```
patterns:
  password-patterns:
    pattern1: "test"
```

Comment: after doing modifications as per your suggestion, "mvn clean package " command is failing.it says, Unable to find main class

Comment: edited further post by adding certain changes in code. please suggest

Comment: it worked. was missing @Component annotation to one of my class.

Comment: I highly recommend putting getters and setters in the AppProperties class as it may fail otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its indentation issue.Just for confirmation put any other direct property

```
amazon:
associateId: habuma-20
```

and try to get it if success then try to use like below.

```
patterns: 
  password_patterns: 
    pattern1: "test"
```

If above doesn't work then try to remove quotes from "test" .

NOTE : Avoid use of tabs http://yaml.org/faq.html

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/troubleshooting/yaml_idiosyncrasies.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Value annotation 
if your yml configuration is

```
management:
 security:
  enabled: true
```

than you can use on @Configuration

```
@Value("${management.security.enabled}")
bolean managementSecurityenabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should fix your indentations:

```
patterns: 
  password_patterns: 
  pattern1: "test"
```

to

```
patterns: 
  password_patterns: 
    pattern1: "test"
```

Second thing to note - you have marked your property class as `@Component` so later it can be found in spring context (also I would suggest to use `@Configuration` here it would be more natural, as it is a configuration), so when you want to use it with populated config properties you should take it from context. 
Next piece of code will give you an ability to use configuration data in your beans:

```
@Autowired
private AppProperties appProperties;
```

Third thing - be sure that somewhere in your `@Configuration` files you have `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation

Also it's not obvious to use a whole AppProperties class under narrow `patterns` tag...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **@Alexander Pankin**`s answer, program might ask you to add `dependency` in **pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```